# Suggest any Error Logging facility for Winforms application for writing error in a remote database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My team working in a project using **Winforms application(c#) & MSSQL 2005** as database.

When I searched the goggle,I found ELMAH, NLog & log4net.I didn't have enough knowledge to implement in Winforms application.

**Please suggest any reference/library for writing Error Logging  for Winforms application & to store in a remote database.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My view is that you should read the docs on log4net. It's a very good logging tool that supports a variety of outputs.

It will log your information to a database with relative ease once you get initial configuration done.

Have a read at this link for a quick start:

[Fast track to Log4Net](http://www.l4ndash.com/Oldmodules/Articles/tabid/69/ctl/ArticleView/mid/413/articleId/3/FasttracktoLog4Netdatabaselogging.aspx)

Comment: I second this suggestion--I've personally used the SmtpAppenders to email error messages, ADO.Net appenders to log to databases, UDP Appenders for monitoring network apps, etc.

Also, the ColoredConsoleAppender is awesome!